# Javascript - extract object ID from a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am not sure if my title is clear enough.  I essentially have a div saved as a Javascript object which looks like this:  `[div#field_30.checkbox_group]`

The field_30 is the ID which I am trying to extract here.  doing something like `object.id` is not working.  Does anyone know how to get the ID?

Note:  I saved the object like this:  `var object = $(".workspace .selected");` which grabs the currently selected div inside the object called workspace.  Sorry is this is a rookie mistake, I just can't seem to find anything anywhere.  Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var object = $(".workspace .selected");` will return a jQuery wrapped element that has jQuery properties and methods rather than element properties and methods. This means that any of

```
object[0].id
object.prop("id")
object.attr("id")
```

should work, but the 1st option should be the best performance-wise. It gets the `id` property of the the 1st element contained by the jQuery object, which is your div.

Answer (score 0):

Your object is in fact a jQuery object, not a dom object.

To use the dom object use,

```
object[0].id
```

Or using, jquery, (Since it is already there)

```
object.prop('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `$jquery_object.attr('id')` or `$jquery_object.eq(0).id`

See this for exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/cquuT/

Answer (score 0):

In this case it looks like `object` is the result of a `jQuery` select.  To get to the actual DOM object you need to use `[0]`.  Then you can access the `id` property

```
object[0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a complete answer here, so I'll provide my own.

If you're using jQuery selector `$()`, then you'll get jQuery-wrapped *collection*, not a single element.

(I assume now that you're using jQuery 1.5.2, the same as StackOverflow uses now.)

- Universal solution to get `id`s of all elements returned by selector is:

  ```
  .map(function(){ return this.id; })
  ```

  Running `$(".post-text").map(function(){ return this.id; })` on current page will return something like: `["", "", "", "", ""]`
- To get `id` of the first element returned by selector use:

  ```
  .attr('id')
  ```

  Running `$("div").attr('id')` on current page will return `"notify-container"`.

  Since jQuery 1.6 you can also use `.prop('id')` here.

If you know, that query will return only one element or you just want the first element matching given selector, then use `.attr` which is obviously a simpler solution.